# whether rabbitmq federation plugin support mqtt messges?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, federation

As title, I'm confused whether rabbitmq federation plugin support both amqp and mqtt.
If mqtt supported, whether addtional configuration needed？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try it out and see for yourself?

Since the MQTT adapter is built on top of AMQP, it interoperates with other RabbitMQ plugins ([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html#overview)). Please carefully read that document to understand how MQTT forward-slashes are translated into what AMQP understands.

Comment: I've read the docs and meet some issue when trying federate exchanges.
The federate exchange link is in running status, while it doesn't push messages from upstream to downstream.
The log in upstream hang here and no more info.
`2018-06-06 06:35:17.534 [info] <0.16256.0> MQTT vhost picked using plugin configuration or default
2018-06-06 06:35:17.539 [info] <0.16256.0> accepting MQTT connection <0.16256.0> (172.*.*.*:55831 -> 192.168.1.145:1883)
2018-06-06 06:35:17.931 [info] <0.16256.0> closing MQTT connection <0.16256.0> (172.*.*.*:55831 -> 192.168.1.145:1883)`

Comment: The rabbitmq-server version is 3.7.0.